# looking basic construction for docusign

Tags: java

I am very new to this. We use DocuSign and looking to have Java automatically send and receive all the documents.  I just downloaded some code from the DocuSign website but it's saying the constructor not found.

Does anyone have one complete program(java) which I can run and get some basic authentication and some envelope information retrieve.

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(AuthServerUrl, "docusignAccessCode", IntegratorKey, ClientSecret);
```

Comment: Also, please do not tag two languages in your question.  [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are as similar to each other as "ham" and "hamster".

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ApiClient class if it has a constructor with 4 parameters you provided? 
I suppose that it has a constructor that accepts 4 Strings. Have you checked that all of your 4 parameters are indeed Strings and not some kind of object?

Answer (score 0):

I do have all the string types and yes, there is constructor exsits…. code is from DocuSign site..

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-code-examples/blob/master/java/JavaSDKSamples.java